# testing WCF services on server

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I'm trying to test my net.tcp binded wcf service on my server machine, the service cannot be accessed from outside, does anyone know any tool that can be helpful to call my service on server 2008 machine?

Answer (score 0):

Host the service in IIS. You can test the service using Integration Tests by adding the service Reference (`net.tcp://localhost:8000/WCFTestService`) in your test project.

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647180.aspx).